# How can I implement single letter domains for LAN internet browsing using dnsmasq?

Tags: domain-name-system, dhcp, dnsmasq, google-chrome, dhcp-option

In our LAN I have several services running in multiple hosts, and clients using DHCP with `dnsmasq`.

My goal is that any user can type a single letter (e.g. `c`) in the browser search bar and get in return the HTTP response of a local HTTP server at 192.168.2.120.

What I've done so far:

`dnsmasq.conf` file in the DHCP LAN server:

```
# (c.com is an example)
# The idea of the below is that clients will append c.com to DNS lookups when they look up for "c"
dhcp-option=option:domain-name,c.com
dhcp-option=option:domain-search,c.com
```

`/etc/hosts` in the DHCP server:

```
192.168.2.120 c.c.com c.com
```

What's working:

- I've confirmed with `tcpdump` that the clients receive the options in the DHCP response.
- `curl c`, `curl c.c.com`, and `curl c.com` all work fine. They all point to 192.168.2.120 and get the expected HTTP traffic.

However, typing "c" in the browser bar triggers a Google search (tested in Firefox/Edge/Chrome). It works only if I type "http://c".

What else I'm missing so that internet browsers can work like `curl`, and don't trigger a search? I know it's possible because I've seen it implemented in some workplaces. I'm missing some part of the puzzle.

Comment: This is because the browser assumes that you want to search for a keyword when you put in a string that is not a valid public domain so you have to dig into the settings of the browser you are using

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/274562/teach-google-chrome-to-understand-custom-tld

Answer (score 0):

@AlexD comment pointed me to the right solution.
Using "c/" (i.e. appending a slash) triggers the expected behaviour.